# Format specifier %s in not showing result

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, string-literals, function-definition

I am learning the C programming language. I am doing homework with C programming language. But I am getting a problem. The result is not printing. I am using format specifier %s. Here is my code below. Please have a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gradeCalculation(int marks) {
  switch (marks) {
    case 0 ... 49:
      return 'F';
      break;
    
    case 50 ... 59:
      return 'D';
      break;

    case 60 ... 69:
      return 'C';
      break;

    case 70 ... 79:
      return 'B';
      break;

    case 80 ... 89:
      return 'A';
      break;

    case 90 ... 100:
      return 'A+';
      break;

    default:
      return 'Marks is not valid!';
  }
}

int main() {
  int marks;

  printf("Marks: ");
  scanf("%d", &marks);

  printf("Grade: %s\n", gradeCalculation(marks));

  return 0;
}
```

How to solve my problem? What specifier should I use to get the expected result?

Comment: `%s` is used on `char *`, since you are only returning an `int`, to get the `char` representation, use `%c`.

Comment: If I use %c then the default case will not print.

Comment: How do you expect `'Marks is not valid!'` to be represented as an `int`?

Comment: I just noticed that, `return 'Marks is not valid!';` is wrong. You should use `" "` (double quotes). And change your function return type to `char *`. That way you can use `%s`.

Comment: change the return type of your function as it is returning string on default case

Comment: Also note that range-based cases like `case 0 ... 49:` are *not* Standard C (it's a GNU extension).

Comment: Change *all* the `return` statements to use `""`!

Comment: You didn't get a compiler error or warning for `'Marks is not valid!'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters case labels like this

```
case 90 ... 100:
```

is not a standard C feature. It is better to use if-else statements. Also the function parameter should have unsigned integer type for example `unsigned int`.

Your function returns an object of the type `int`

```
int gradeCalculation(int marks) {
```

So using the conversion specifier `%s` with an object of the type `int` results in undefined behavior.

The function return type should be `const char *`

```
const char * gradeCalculation( unsigned int marks ) {
```

and instead of integer character literals you need to return string literals as for example

```
case 80 ... 89:
  return "A";
  break;

case 90 ... 100:
  return "A+";
  break;

default:
  return "Marks is not valid!";
```

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * gradeCalculation( unsigned int marks ) 
{
    const char *grade = "Marks is not valid!";

    if ( marks < 50 )
    {
        grade = "F";
    }
    else if ( marks < 60 )
    {
        grade = "D";
    }
    else if ( marks < 70 )
    {
        grade = "C";
    }
    else if ( marks < 80 )
    {
        grade = "B";
    }
    else if ( marks < 90 )
    {
        grade = "A";
    }
    else if ( marks <= 100 )
    {
        grade = "A+";
    }

    return grade;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int marks = 0;

    printf("Marks: ");
    scanf( "%u", &marks );

    printf( "Grade: %s\n", gradeCalculation( marks ) );

    return 0;
}
```

.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution solved my problem. I accidentally used single quotation instead of double quotation.

Answer (score 1):

Apostrophes denote character constants; `F` is an integer that is the code for the character “F”.

For various legacy/history reasons, you can have multi-character constants such as `A+`, which has a value that may combine the values of the two characters “A” and “+”. However, the result is still an `int`; it is not generally treated as a string of two characters. Multi-character constants are used for special purposes and are implementation-dependent. You should avoid them outside of special circumstances.

In `gradeCalculation`, you want to return a string of characters. To refer to a string, we generally use a pointer to its first element. So make the return type of `gradeCalculation` `const char *`. Then change all the character constants to string literals, such as `"F"`, `"A+"`, and `"Marks is not valid"`. Note the use of quotation marks rather than apostrophes. A string literal denotes an array of characters including a null character to mark the end.

Answer (score 1):

There are few points to be noted in your given code:

1. In the line `printf("Grade: %s\n", gradeCalculation(marks));` , the function `gradeCalculation()` returns an `int` whereas the format specifier is `%s` which is for a string(char *).
2. In the `int gradeCalculation(int marks)`, all the cases are returning a character, except for

   `case 90 ... 100:`

   `return 'A+';`

   `break;`

   `default:`

   `return 'Marks is not valid!';`

which are returning string.

Therefore, it will be good to convert all to string and change the return type to `char *`, i.e., string.

Below is the solution :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * gradeCalculation(int marks) {
  switch (marks) {
    case 0 ... 49:
      return "F";
      break;
    
    case 50 ... 59:
      return "D";
      break;

    case 60 ... 69:
      return "C";
      break;

    case 70 ... 79:
      return "B";
      break;

    case 80 ... 89:
      return "A";
      break;

    case 90 ... 100:
      return "A+";
      break;

    default:
      return "Marks is not valid!";
  }
}

int main() {
  int marks;

  printf("Marks: ");
  scanf("%d", &marks);

  printf("Grade: %s\n", gradeCalculation(marks));

  return 0;
}
```